# How to create feature branch in GIT based on two branches?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, branch

I have a problem basically I want to create a feature branch. What I have done is create a feature branch named TEST_RUN based from master (let's say master is Q1) then this will make a FB TEST_RUN with exactly the same as master right?

But I want some folders in TEST_RUN to be based in let's say Q2 which hasn't go live yet since master is still Q1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. You can merge from many parent commits. This is an octopus merge. I’m an unfamiliar with the exact command though (I know it uses `git merge`)

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Practically, depends on how the things you want have been committed etc. Cherry picking may work, but why is there such a need?

Comment: Hi, for example in master (which is Q1) we have 3 folders (a, b, and c). I created feature branch based on master so technically a,b and c folders in my feature branch are based on Q1 but I want folder 'C' to be based on Q2 which is not the master since Q2 is not yet go live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, if I understand the question, then this is what you want:

```
on branch-Master(Q1): has a, b, c

from branch Master(Q1) -> checkout/switch to Feature branch(F) 
> git checkout -b F
From Feature branch(F): git merge `Q2`
> git merge Q2
```

Please let me know further if it does not work.

Edit:

```
If you want only a file from Q2:
git checkout Q2 file1

If you want entire folder from Q2: 
git checkout Q2 -- c

Note: c is the folder from Q2,  c could be a directory path as well, like :
  folder1/c

But its not a git merge.
```

Comment: thank you S Sourav. But I want only folder 'C' in branch(F) to be in Q2. If I do git merge Q2 this will merge also other folders right?

Comment: Yes, so will have completely different contents than master(Q1) in your feature branch? If you only want 'C' which is the content of Q2 then why you are creating new feature branch(F)? Again, having independent branches in a Git repo is similar to having independent projects. If you still want to make a separate branch other than base branch content then if you make any accidental marge, it may cause a marge conflict sometime.

Comment: Just to be clear. Q2 has also folders a, b, and c. Contents of Q1 and Q2 are different from each other. It's like a want a combination of both. (i.e. Feature Branch will have folders from Q1 (a, b) and a folder from Q2 (c).

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late update, we had CVS to GIT migration over the weekend. I will try your suggestion cause that's what I need to checkout only certain folder from Q2 then merge it with a branch(F). I will also post a screenshot for better visuals :)

Comment: sure :-) . Let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Hi S Sourav, I have tried today and git checkout Q2 -- c worked but i'm confused since i'm trying to merge this with the Q1 branch(F) and it's not working :(